# Place a Javascript variable into a php variable as output?

Tags: javascript, php

The code below represents the concept I am after. I am trying place a simple javascript variable into a simple php variable and out put it.

I realize this code doesn;t work, but it reprents what I am attempting to do.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

    $('#myModal').on('show.bs.modal', function (event) {

    var button = $(event.relatedTarget) 
    var trackid = button.data('trackid')

    var modal = $(this)

    modal.find('.modal-title').html('<p><?php $favid =' + trackid + '; ?></p>')
    })

</script>
```

Comment: Can this be done with json_encode?

Comment: Javascript runs on the client, PHP runs on the server. The PHP script is all done by the time the Javascript runs.

Comment: You can't pass a JavaScript variable to PHP on the current page because JavaScript is run on the clients browser, while PHP is on the server. To be able to pass a JavaScript variable to PHP you'll need to be an `AJAX` call to the same page and a `GET` from PHP to receive the variable, however, the page will need to be refreshed.

Comment: It's not even clear why you need to run PHP at all in this example. Just do `.html('<p>' + trackid + '</p>')`

Comment: it is a single variable - any simple ajax examples that you can point me to (in the meantime, I'll search) Thank You for the direction....

Comment: I will use it later in the page to perform an INSERT query based on this trackid variable... If I can get to populate the variable on page load, I can do the rest...

Comment: I currently have the id display through JS on the page - I just need it to be placed in the PHP variable --- this is working already in terms of plain HTML output --- modal.find('.modal-title').html('Track ID: ' + trackid '; ?></p>')